Как считать звуки?

Ногою твердой стать при море.  Сюда по новым им волнам  Все флаги в
гости будут к нам,  И запируем на просторе.

Почему в ответах 32 и 33 звонких согласных звука? Я насчитала 34.

Вы, наверное, лишний звонкий в слове все увидели. Его в этом слове нет: [ф]се.

Хотя… Надо подумать, как произносится окончание в слове запируем. Может, с йотом? Тогда да, 34.

Как раз нет. Именно [ф] там нашла. А в "запируем" я увидела [й']: [ з а п' и р У j' и(э) м] = з, р, й, м.
